# PHP requiring a file that is 2 directories back

Tags: php, path

The current file is located at this

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\includes\Db
```

I want to go down back to the includes folder and select a file, but this code is giving me an error. saying that the path is in valid how do I go back down to the includes folder then select a another folder inside the includes folder and then include that certain file?

here's what I've done

```
require_once("../../includes/Db_Resources/db_connection.php");
```

Comment: You could try using an absolute path, instead of a relative one?

Comment: You can still have an absolute path; there's nothing wrong with using `require_once("C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\includes\Db_Resources\db_connection.php");` - though you might need to escape out the backslashes.

Comment: @user962206: Than your file is not there. Verify your path.

Comment: how do I verify my path?

Comment: Open up Windows Explorer, and enter the path into it; see if the file is in the directory that appears.

Comment: I opened it and that connection file is here C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\includes\Db_Resources but it still gives me an error

Answer (score 4):

You are going too shallow. You only need to go one level deep:

```
require_once("../Db_Resources/db_connection.php");
```

Comment: it gave me these errors 
Warning: require_once(../includes/Db_Resources/db_connection.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\includes\Db\Accounts.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../includes/Db_Resources/db_connection.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\includes\Db\Accounts.php on line 2

Comment: Try resolving the path with `realpath()` and see if you get anything. Also, make sure the file you're trying to access it actually there. I've edited my code, try now.

Comment: I've tried your code it gave me this error

Warning: require_once(./includes/Accounts.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\login.php on line 7

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required './includes/Accounts.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\login.php on line 7

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

require_once("C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\includes\Db\YOUR_CONNECTION_FILE.php");

it'll work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding an answer to an older question it is helpful to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. In this case does providing the full path add any value? What are the downsides of hard coding a path? Why is it not done? Code should be formatted as such using the button in the editor with the curly braces, or by directly using markdown to do so.